# Getting release dates from themoviedb.org API for DVDs

Tags: api, dvd, themoviedb-api

I'm trying to find out how to get movies from themoviedb.org API based on DVD release dates.  I only want to return DVD releases and not movies still in the theater.

I read somewhere that they now have support for `digital release dates`.  Looking at the info on their API I found the following...

[API Reference Page](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/movies/movieidreleasedates)

```
/movie/id/release_dates

Get the release dates, certifications and related information by country for a specific movie id.

The results are keyed by iso_3166_1 code and contain a type value which on our system, maps to:

1. Premiere
2. Theatrical (limited)
3. Theatrical
4. Digital
5. Physical
6. TV

Required Parameters
  api_key

Optional Parameters
  append_to_response    Comma separated, any movie method
```

Does someone know how to do this?  I was hoping for an example URL to show me what to use.  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got this correct but I'm using the TMDB api for my project as well. To get the digital release you add the `release_dates` to the url. So in my case it would like this:

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/271110?api_key=**f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=release_dates&callback=angular.callbacks._1

Notice `append_to_response=release_dates`

This returns json like so:

```
{
  "adult":false,
  "backdrop_path":"/rqAHkvXldb9tHlnbQDwOzRi0yVD.jpg",
  "belongs_to_collection":{
     "id":131295,
     "name":"Captain America Collection",
     "poster_path":"/2tOgiY533JSFp7OrVlkeRJvsZpI.jpg",
     "backdrop_path":"/nZSYqitBkAvmoq5IrsGsSWuhSC8.jpg"
  },
  "budget":250000000,
  "genres":[
     {
        "id":28,
        "name":"Action"
     },
     {
        "id":53,
        "name":"Thriller"
     },
     {
        "id":878,
        "name":"Science Fiction"
     }
  ],
  "homepage":"http://marvel.com/captainamericapremiere",
  "id":271110,
  "imdb_id":"tt3498820",
  "original_language":"en",
  "original_title":"Captain America: Civil War",
  "overview":"Following the events of Age of Ultron, the collective governments of the world pass an act designed to regulate all superhuman activity. This polarizes opinion amongst the Avengers, causing two factions to side with Iron Man or Captain America, which causes an epic battle between former allies.",
  "popularity":59.186478,
  "poster_path":"/5N20rQURev5CNDcMjHVUZhpoCNC.jpg",
  "production_companies":[
     {
        "name":"Marvel Studios",
        "id":420
     }
  ],
  "production_countries":[
     {
        "iso_3166_1":"US",
        "name":"United States of America"
     }
  ],
  "release_date":"2016-04-27",
  "revenue":1152000000,
  "runtime":146,
  "spoken_languages":[
     {
        "iso_639_1":"ro",
        "name":"Română"
     },
     {
        "iso_639_1":"en",
        "name":"English"
     },
     {
        "iso_639_1":"de",
        "name":"Deutsch"
     },
     {
        "iso_639_1":"ru",
        "name":"Pусский"
     }
  ],
  "status":"Released",
  "tagline":"Divided We Fall",
  "title":"Captain America: Civil War",
  "video":false,
  "vote_average":6.9,
  "vote_count":2740,
  "release_dates":{
     "results":[
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"BR",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"12",
                 "iso_639_1":"pt",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"IN",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"UA",
                 "iso_639_1":"en",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"TH",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"PG-13",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-27T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"GB",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"12A",
                 "iso_639_1":"en",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"PH",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"IE",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"KZ",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"RO",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"AR",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"IL",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"GR",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"ES",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"CA",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"PG",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"SG",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"PT",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"TR",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"DK",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"11",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"BY",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"CL",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"FI",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"CH",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-27T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"FR",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"Paris",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-18T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":1
              },
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-27T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"IT",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"RU",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"16+",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":1
              },
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              },
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"ru",
                 "note":"BD-50, DVD-9",
                 "release_date":"2016-08-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":5
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"NO",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"SE",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"HU",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-12T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"EE",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"NZ",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"MX",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"BG",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"DE",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"12",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"Berlin",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-21T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":1
              },
              {
                 "certification":"12",
                 "iso_639_1":"de",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"AU",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"M",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"PL",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"AZ",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"NL",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"MY",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-05T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"JP",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "iso_3166_1":"US",
           "release_dates":[
              {
                 "certification":"PG-13",
                 "iso_639_1":"en",
                 "note":"Los Angeles, California",
                 "release_date":"2016-04-12T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":1
              },
              {
                 "certification":"PG-13",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "note":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":3
              },
              {
                 "certification":"PG-13",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":4
              },
              {
                 "certification":"PG-13",
                 "iso_639_1":"",
                 "release_date":"2016-09-13T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "type":5
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

}

There's a lot of data in here, but we are looking for type: `4. Digital`. So looking through the data it shows:

```
{
  "certification":"PG-13",
  "iso_639_1":"",
  "release_date":"2016-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  "type":4
},
```

So it looks like the release date in this case is `2016-09-02` which seems wrong to me. So maybe change that on the API (if you have acces) since blu-ray.com says it's comming `Sep 13, 2016 (5 Days)` Or maybe I'm doing it wrong :)

// edit. I just changed the digital release date so it's the same as amazon :). So in short what you need to do is create the url by appending the release_dates:

the standard info:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/
```

Then the id of the movie:

```
271110
```

Then your api key
?api_key=**f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4

Then the append_to

&append_to_response=release_dates

Fun fact, you can (now) append multiple "things"! Instead of doing 5 different calls. So you could do something like this:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/271110?api_key=**f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=credits,images,videos,release_dates
```

This also adds actors, images and video's to the json. Such a great api!